# Type mismatch: cannot convert from HSSFWorkbook to Workbook

Tags: java, ant, apache-poi, classpath

I have the below code.

```
Workbook srcWorkBook;
Workbook tgtWorkbook;
if((src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("."),src.length()).equals(".xlsx"))){
    srcWorkBook=new XSSFWorkbook(excelFileSrc);
}else{
    srcWorkBook=new HSSFWorkbook(excelFileSrc);
}
```

It is running properly through standalone file, But during my ant compile it is throwing error

```
 [javac] found   : org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
 [javac] required: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
```

I checked my classpath and it does not have any duplicate instances of Jars. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the error suggests you either have an older copy of the main Apache POI jar on your classpath, or are using mis-matched POI jars. See [this POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for some code that will help you track down what jar you are really using, and [this POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for more on mixing POI jars between versions not being supported.

Secondly, your code itself isn't ideal. Instead, you should be using [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) to instantiate the correct Workbook class for you. Change your code to instead be:

```
Workbook srcWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(excelFileSrc));
```

That will identify the file type for you, and create the right one of `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook` for you